# Why does "embed interop types" need to be set to false for SAPbobsCOM.dll in SAP b1 project?

Tags: c#, casting, com, interop, sapb1

In my first SAP B1 project I set Embed Interop Types to True for the `SAPbobsCom.dll`. This was a "DI API" add-on project, i.e. there was no need to run the add-on from inside SAP B1. The code I created compiled just fine and I thought I was OK.

However, a new requirement arose that it would have to run inside SAP B1. Long story short, I realized that in order to package the add-on the SAP b1 tools required that I set Embed Interop Types to False.

I then found some articles in SAP forums indicating that it was advisable to set interop types to false, otherwise it would "cause problems". But no explanation was given as to why, or what the problems would be.  I am wondering whether this is a problem that is specific to the SAP classes, or to COM, or something else. Why would that setting change the way the classes behave?

When I attempted to recompile the add-on with Embed Interop Types set to False many of the statements that used SAPbobsCOM classes failed. The errors were of the form:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'xyz' to 'abc'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

For example, in order to get the statement:

```
objRecSetDN = SapObjects.oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)
```

to compile, I had to change it to:

```
objRecSetDN = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)SapObjects.oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)
```

And I had to change:

```
string CheckSend = RS.Fields.Item("U_Send").Value;
```

to:

```
string CheckSend = (string)RS.Fields.Item("U_Send").Value;
```

Comment: thank you Marvin Fischer for your edit suggestion. I am new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been making SAP B1 AddOns for years and have never set `Embed Interop Types` to false. I do not think you have to do this. This is for addons added using the .ard file and programs running outside of B1.
This applies also to `SAPbouiCom.dll`.

I package my addons within Visual Studio using the `B1DESetup_B192` tool and there is no such requirement as you stated above. See image below.

[image]

Comment: what version of SAP b1 and what version of SAPbobsCOm.dll?

Comment: When you write statements referencing the SAPbobsCOM classes do you always explicitly cast the result as in the examples I gave, like:          objRecSetDN = (SAPbobsCOM.Recordset)SapObjects.oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)

Comment: Yes I do that always

Comment: I think the issue is that if Embed Interop Types is set to True then you don't "have to" write the explicit casts, but you can if you want. But if Interop is set to false then you MUST make the explicit cast or it won't compile. So I think that because you are writing explicit casts you haven't run into the problem, either way.  My question is not just about whether it is or isn't required, but is also about COM and why that setting changes the way the classes behave.